# Someone break this block down for me please

Tags: ruby

Ok this is my understanding.

1. `prices.combination(2)`-makes an subarray [10,11][2,9]...
2. `.map` - creates an array
3. `do |buy,sell| [buy, sell, sell-buy]` - This is the first part I'm confused on. the |buy,sell| looks normal to me but the following array I've never seen before. All the blocks I've written are similar to prices do |i| i * 2 end. How does an array after the iterator work?

4  `.end.max_by` - finds the largest sum of the previous sell-buy??

5. `do |buy, sell, profit| profit` - How did profit come into the picture? How did we go from sell-buy to profit?
6. I understand what everything is doing I just don't understand this structure. Looking for a good explanation.

   ```
   a = [10, 11, 2, 9, 4, 3, 5, 6]

   def max_profit(prices)
     prices.combination(2).map do |buy, sell|
       [buy, sell, sell - buy]
     end.max_by do |buy, sell, profit|
       profit
     end
   end

   max_profit(a)
   ```

Comment: Hey Jacob, please reformat your question. Create a codeblock (indent with four spaces) and then add comments (the `#` symbol in ruby) on each line expaning your thoughts. However you do it, you need to make a the code 100% readable or your question will start receiving downvotes.

Comment: Someone just edited it for me while I was trying to do the same. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does an array after the iterator work?

The same way any expression in a block works.  Ruby will evaluate the expression, and if it's the last expression in the block, Ruby will use the result as a value of the block.  In this case, the expression creates a new array with three elements.  Nothing special is happening.

So when you write `.map { |buy, sell| [buy, sell, sell - buy] }`, that is a scrap of Ruby code that be applied to an array with buy and sell prices, and returns a new array where each item has a buy price, a sell price, and a profit.   In case you didn't know, people working with money usually define their profit to be the money they earned (e.g. for selling an item) minus the money they spent (e.g. buying the item).  So this block computes the profit from the buy and sell prices.  If you were working in Excel, that scrap of Ruby code would be the equivalent of adding a new column and using a formula to set each cell equal to the difference of the values in the first two columns.

Moving on, you're confused about `.max_by { |buy, sell, profit| profit }`.  It just selects the element in the array with the largest profit.  The block is passed as an argument to `max_by`, so that `max_by` knows what exactly you want to maximize.  Look up the documentation for Enumerable#max_by if you are still confused.

By the way, a great way to understand Ruby code is to print out intermediate results.  Try running this code so you can see what the array looks after you calculated the profit but before you ran `max_by`:

```
def max_profit(prices)
  tmp = prices.combination(2).map do |buy, sell|
    [buy, sell, sell - buy]
  end

  p tmp  # print out tmp nicely

  tmp.max_by do |buy, sell, profit|
    profit
  end
end
```

Comment: so by chaining max_by to [buy,sell,profit] you are assigning the value of max_by to profit. Right?

Comment: No, `max_by` is a function you are calling, not a value.  You shouldn't think about changing a function; functions are defined and then they are called.  Did you look at the doc yet?  Here is is: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by

Comment: Ahhh after the reading the documentation again it's clear now. That was a huge help.